# Error in adding post to a blog programmatically

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, sharepoint-addin

I used linq to insert post into blog programmatically but when i clicked button error is appeared [image]

Comment: You kind of should tell us what button you clicked and what the error details are :)

Comment: button that create post in blog and its code is above in pic and error details are                                                                        Error 
An unexpected error has occurred. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: b4b3a639-7d79-4ba5-bf51-2fb783a7cf3a 

Date and Time: 6/7/2013 7:49:58 PM

Comment: Can you check the log for that correlation ID and see what the log message is and post it here?

Comment: i checked blog and didn't found post , i thought problems because there are 2 lookup columns in post list

Comment: It's hard for me to tell what column types you are using just based on the variable names. Like I said, you should definitely look into the 12/14 hive LOGS folder (depending on your SharePoint version) to see what the exact error message is for the correlation ID. This will help narrow down the problem (I know it usually helps for me whenever an error occurs!)